# How to make a JTable row to an "unselected" state after selected any row in that table?

Tags: java, swing, select, jtable

I'm developing a Java Swing application which contains a `JTable`. By default, while launching the application for the first time, the call to the method `jtable.getSelectedRow()` or `jtable.getSelectedColumn()` returns -1, which means that no row selected at that moment. After user clicked any row or column, the call to the method `jtable.getSelectedRow()` or `jtable.getSelectedColumn()` returns the appropriate values of selected rows & columns. What I actually need is that I want to set the selected row or column to -1 i.e. "no row or column selected state". How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The JTable method `clearSelection` will do what you want -- clear the selection of all the table's selected rows and columns. The JTable API is the place to look for methods such as these.